# How to constuct a MySQL query which will return a flag, either returning y or n based on the rows in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here are my tables:

```
foo1
------
| id |
------
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
------
```

And:

```
foo2
------------------
| id | id2 | foo |
------------------
| 1  |  1  |  2  |
| 2  |  1  |  1  |
| 3  |  3  |  2  |
| 4  |  3  |  1  |
| 5  |  5  |  1  |
------------------
```

Basically, I want to select all the rows in `foo1` with an id which is corresponding to the `id2` of `foo2`, and also return a `flag` column containing `y` if there is a row in `foo2` with the same `id2` as an `id` in `foo1`, and has `foo` equal to `2`, and `n` otherwise. For example, this is what the query should return from my two example tables:

```
-------------
| id | flag |
-------------
| 1  |   y  |
| 3  |   y  |
| 5  |   n  |
-------------
```

Note how the flag returned for id = 1 is `y`, not `n`, as there is at least one row with `id2` equal to `1`, and `foo` equal to `2`.

Is such a query possible?

Comment: What you need is `LEFT JOIN`, I'm sure you could solve it yourself now

Comment: @zerkms I'm sorry, I'm not that familiar with SQL. If you could, please help me construct a query.

Comment: so you're here to find people doing your work for free or for learning?

Comment: @zerkms What a nice way to put it. But yes, I am here for learning.

Comment: it's barely a learning - do you understand now how `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` work? Why is `MAX()` used there? Will you be able to write something similar by yourself?

Comment: @zerkms Obviously not, or why would I bother to ask a question?

Comment: "But yes, I am here for learning", "Obviously not". So you're here for learning and you, "obviously" didn't get smarter after this question. Reasonable question: do you still think your way to become a better developer efficient?

Comment: @zerkms No, not anymore, as I am chatting with someone not helping me shape the road to becoming one.

Comment: you will never become one if instead of asking the general solutions or a reference to a documentation you'll ask the complete solution for a particular issue. The particular solutions are rarely helpful from learning perspective. But, well, it's up to you how to do that. You think it's a right thing to do - good luck with that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.ID, 
        IF(c.id2 IS NULL, 'n', 'y') flag
FROM    foo1 a
        INNER JOIN foo2 b
            ON a.ID = b.id2 
        LEFT JOIN foo2 c
            ON b.id2 = c.id2 AND
                c.foo = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7271b/4)

Comment: @JW.: stop giving fishes! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select foo1.id id, if(max(foo2.foo = 2), 'y', 'n') flag
from foo1 join foo2 on foo1.id = foo2.id2
group by id
```

Comment: you can use this fiddle if you want to: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7271b/7 `:D`